# Code-challenge: How fast can you calculate 1000! with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have got a challenge to calculate 1000! with Powershell as fast as possible.
Here the given rules for this code-challenge:

- no predefined arrays or strings (except for initial 0!-value)
- no use of external modules or embedded C# code
- routine must be correct for any input from 0 till 1000
- result-string must be created as part of the measurement

Based on this conditions I could create the below code-snippet as a first draft.
Is there any idea to improve the speed? Inputs are more than welcome!

```
cls
Remove-Variable * -ea 0

$in = 1000

$runtime = measure-command {


    # define initial arr with 0! = 1:
    $arr = [System.Collections.Generic.List[uint64]]::new()
    $arr.Add(1)
    if ($in -gt 1) {

        # define block-dimension per array-entry:
        $posLen = 16
        $multiplier = [uint64][math]::Pow(10,$posLen)

        # calculate faculty:
        $start = 0
        foreach($i in 2..$in) {
            $div = 0
            if ($arr[$start] -eq 0){$start++}
            foreach($p in $start..($arr.Count-1)) {
                $mul = $i * $arr[$p] + $div
                $arr[$p] = $mul % $multiplier
                $div = [math]::Floor($mul/$multiplier)
            }
            if ($div -gt 0) {$arr.Add($div)}
        }
    }

    # convert array into string-result:
    $max = $arr.count-1
    $faculty = $arr[$max].ToString()
    if ($max -gt 1) {
        foreach($p in ($max-1)..0) {
            $faculty += ($multiplier + $arr[$p]).ToString().Substring(1)
        }
    }
}

# check:
if ($in -eq 1000 -and !$faculty.StartsWith('402387260077') -or $faculty.length -ne 2568) {
    write-host 'result is not OK.' -f y 
}

# show result:
write-host 'runtime:' $runtime.TotalSeconds 'sec.'
write-host "`nfaculty of $in :`n$faculty"
```

Comment: Current runtime on my 4-year old Laptop is ca. 0.52 seconds.
Is there any smart way to go with bit-shifts instead of divisions?

Comment: I found this reference link, but don't see how to adopt this into Powershell http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/Benchmark.html

Comment: The output from your implementation is not correct btw - the last three-digit group before the trailing zeros is `472`, but yours produce a number where those digits are `912`

Comment: Do note that this challenge is pretty silly. One does not use scripting languages like PowerShell for number crunching, and if you do performance is probably not your first concern -- just getting it to work at all without a lot of awkward code would be. This is a bit like arranging for a race between bumper cars -- technically possible but not very meaningful. Given that the obvious solution is to leverage `BigInteger` and be done with it I have to wonder if it's not just a big "gotcha" to see if you know about/can find this type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way is to rely on the existing multiplication capabilities of a data type designed specifically for large integers - like `[bigint]`:

```
$in = 1000

$runtime = Measure-Command {
  # handle 0!
  $n = [Math]::Max($in, 1)
  $b = [bigint]::new($n)

  while(--$n -ge 1){
    $b *= $n
  }
}

Clear-Host
Write-Host "Runtime: $($runtime.TotalSeconds)"
Write-Host "Factorial of $in is: `n$b"
```

This gives me a runtime of ~18ms, contrasting with ~300ms using your `[uint64]`-based carry approach :)

As Jeroen Mostert points out, you may be able to attain an additional improvement by side-stepping the `*=` operator and calling `[BigInt]::Multiply` directly:

```
# change this line
$b *= $n
# to this
$b = [bigint]::Multiply($b, $n)
```

I believe all the constraints are met as well:

> no predefined arrays or strings (except for initial 0!-value)

- Check!

> no use of external modules or embedded C# code

- Check! (`[bigint]` is part of the .NET base class library)

> routine must be correct for any input from 0 till 1000

- Check!

> result-string must be created as part of the measurement

- We're already tracking the result as an integer, thereby implicitly storing the string representation

Comment: Just to show how finicky timing scripting is because most of the time is spent on the silly stuff, on my machine (with PowerShell 7.2 on Linux) the loop runs about twice as fast if `$b *= $n` is replaced with `$b = [bigint]::Multiply($b, $n)`, whereas giving `$b` a static type of `[bigint]` actually slows things down. Mileage can vary with different versions of PowerShell, of course.

Comment: @JeroenMostert first one is not super surprising, but are you seeing _significant_ slowdown when applying a type attribute to `$b`? I'd expect only "light overhead" given the assigned values are all already `[bigint]`'s....

Comment: Yes you'd expect that, wouldn't you? But the benchmark don't lie: 2.2 ms if `$b` is declared like a regular variable, 2.7 if it's typed. This isn't a *huge* difference, but still measurable, and the fact that there's a difference at all, and that it's *slower*, is very surprising to me as an outsider who's used to static typing (but no doubt perfectly explainable if you look at the innards of the interpreter).

Comment: @JeroenMostert It is indeed explainable (variable resolution + attribute resolution + conversion check + conversion + assignment will undoubtedly be slower that just variable resolution + assignment). Thanks for sharing the results! :)

Comment: They totally fooled me with this hint to convert it into a string at the end. Going with BigInt is the solution here. Thank you!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen minor issue: your solution returns 0! as 0 instead of 1. As Jeroen mentioned, the Multiply seems to be faster. I also changed the while-loop to a foreach. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Carsten Good catch, added handling of `0` + Jeroen's excellent suggestion :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen whats the reason for the [bigint]::parse() ?

Comment: @Carsten Force of habit, `Parse()` is usually safer than casting numeric literals, better preserved precision. But completely unnecessary in this case :)